# What is integrity_test?

Tags: testing

I'm going through Substrate and see some places implement integrity_test as Hooks function to check some variables values.
My question is what is integrity_test? and when we should implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrity test function is some logic that you can place in your pallet, that will then be executed in the `construct_runtime!` in your final runtime configuration.

Note that this function does not have access to storage, since it is happening at compile time, where there is no chain state.

You can use this function to make assertions about how your runtime is configured to ensure that it makes sense. For example, if you have some configurations like `T::MinValue` and `T::MaxValue`, then you can make an assertion like:

```rust
#[pallet::hooks]
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    fn integrity_test() {
        // Some code that will run in a test in the `construct_runtime!`.
        assert!(T::MinValue::get() <= T::MaxValue::get())
    }
}
```

Then, if a user configured things wrong in their final runtime, the overall integrity test would fail.

Comment: this idea is interesting, how can I see it's worked?
```cargo build``` and ```cargo check``` didn't.

Comment: You need to run tests on the crate which contains the `construct_runtime!`, so `cargo test -p node-template-runtime`, or potentially some special test/mock function in your pallet tests.